# What is meant by Generations of Garbage Collector?

Tags: c#, .net

What is meant by Generations of Garbage Collector in C#? Is it different from the concept or is GENERATION only a term used to represent the time period?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A GC generation relates to how many garbage collections an object survives.

All objects start in generation 0. When a garbage collection occurs, and a generation N object cannot be collected, it is moved to generation N+1.

The generations are used to performance optimize garbage collection. It is generally true that generation 0:

1. Is a small fraction of the entire heap in size
2. Has a lot of short-lived objects.

Therefore, when garbage collection occurs, the garbage collector starts by collecting generation 0, which will be quick. If enough memory could be released, no need to look at the older generations, and therefore, collection can happen quickly.

Books could be written about the subject; but to start with, there is some great details in [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973837.aspx), or the [reference here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0xy59wtx.aspx).

Comment: Driis:- "No need to look at older generations" means?? What I am getting here is that if there is enough memory then Generation N and N+1 will not be looked..is it right or am I missing something?

Comment: +1. @RahulTripathi, there are just 3 generations (0, 1, 2) which have specific sets of rules when each generation is included in collection. Links provided by driis (and any article I've seen so far) go into great details on each of generations.

Comment: @RahulTripathi yes, and as Alexei comments, there are generations 0, 1 and 2. Objects in generation 2 are said to be long-lived objects.